# Prior to the 1800s are there any examples of a (preferably mortal) being described as possessing telekinetic abilities in the modern sense?

Tags: folklore, origins, magic

For the purposes of this question, by telekinesis I mean the generalized ability to pick up and move most objects at will, not the ability to move a particular object under specific circumstances (like having a weapon return to one's grip).

Psychokinesis might be the most common power of a "magic" workers in popular culture, but in myth and folklore it seems uncommon. Essentially the earliest descriptions I have been able to find of it come from 1800s mediums, only around 50 years before the word was coined. So I am wondering if the concept of telekinesis as we know it is purely a modern(ish) invention or if there is actually a folkloric or mythological background. I am open to any examples (mystics, monks, wizards, shaman, ect). Thank you!

Comment: Does Moses parting the Red Sea count?

Comment: Commanding invisible spirits to move thing doesn't cut it?  Because off the top of my head, I think it would be explained as that.

Comment: @Chenmunka I thought of that as being close, but in context it seems less like a true "power" per say, and more of a boon granted to Moses by God under specific circumstances for a specific purpose. Based on the story as I understand it, he would not of been thought capable of then levitating a boulder or such, just being the instrument of God's power under specific circumstances. I may be in error though as I am not very familiar with the Bible.

Comment: @Mary Commanding invisible spirits produces a similar effect, but since then it's more of a power of communication or bargaining it isn't quite the same in my opinion. Though that does bring to mind why a power that seems so simple and easy to describe would be relatively rare or absent. Because people in supernatural folklore/myth tended to anthropomorphize objects/forces so much that it was actually might of been more of a leap for someone to work magic without some kind of bargaining or communication.

Answer (score 2):

There is a tale in the Mahabharata (ca. 400 BCE) about [Shakuni](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shakuni) manipulating the outcome of dice throws so that his opponent loses his kingdom and his wife until Krsna intervenes and saves the woman from rape.

There's also a so-called technique called "[touchless knockout](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Touchless_knockout)" in martial arts that is described as being "mastered" in various texts dating long before the 1800s, usually described as "[flowery boxing(花拳)](https://www.quword.com/search?word=%E8%8A%B1%E6%8B%B3)". A period that sees many of these "schools" claiming such techniques appearing is the late Ming-Early Qing Dynasties (ca. 1640) as a reaction to the rising Manchu influence and ultimate dominion in imperial China. The Manchu had a ruthless, aggressive fighting style, so the "flowery boxing" is regarded as a (not very effective) cultural countermovement.

> Martial arts practice during the Qing was generally discussed by
> martial artists using terms specific to the system of practice itself.
> The most common way for them to refer to their practice was by name.
> systems such as plum flower boxing (梅花拳), eight trigrams boxing (八卦拳),
> etc. were generally discussed by name without a generic term being
> applied. For those who were attempting to classify martial arts
> practices, a distinction was usually made between the so called
> External School (外家), which were considered to focus on muscular and
> physical strength, and the Internal School (内家), which were defined by
> their focus on meditation and strength derived from the manipulation
> of qi (气), or internal life force. This language used primarily by
> martial artists defined their practice by the specific set of
> techniques or skills they studied and grouped them by what those
> practices had in common. - from *[Internal Cultivation or External Strength?: Claiming Martial Arts in the Qing Period](https://etd.ohiolink.edu/apexprod/rws_etd/send_file/send?accession=osu1557155402412377&disposition=inline)*

Comment: Fascinating! Thank you, I thought that India was the best bet. Glad to see an example.